# Ruby on Rails Wicked PDF Template Missing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf

I am currently using rails 7 with wicked pdf . wicked pdf is throwing me an missing template error even if I have template file at exact place? what am i doing wrong?

```
  def show
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
     render pdf: "file_name", template: "stocks/pdf.html.erb"
    end
   end
 end
```

what am i doing wrong ?
I am using tailwindcss with jsbuild if that matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in case your template is `stocks/pdf.html.erb`, your render should be as following:

```
format.pdf do
  render pdf: "file_name", template: "stocks/pdf", formats: [:html]
end
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Cheers

Comment: It worked perfectly thank you very much. but what I did in question worked for me in other projects. I wonder what is the difference between the two?

Comment: I think rails 7 requires changes as I proposed in the answer or to change template name to `stocks/pdf.pdf.erb` and then you don't have to specify formats during rendering.

Comment: + a million for beating out chat GPT on this. Thank you so much @zauzaj!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked only if I do:

```
<%= link_to "File", data_path(data, format: :pdf) %>
```

in orders_controller:

```
def data
   format.pdf do
      render pdf: "file_name", template: "orders/data", formats: [:html]
    end
end
```

The file is in "orders/data.html.erb" path